# Proper way of setting slideIndex google slides api

Tags: python, google-slides-api, google-slides

I've created an Image with [`CreateImageRequest`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#CreateImageRequest) and after the creation I'm updating the `imageProperties` with [`UpdateImagePropertiesRequest`](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateimagepropertiesrequest) so I can assign the image a specific [slide index link](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/other#link). So the `requests` array looks like:

```
[{
    'createImage': {
      'objectId': object_id,
      'url': url,
      'elementProperties': {
        'pageObjectId': page_id,
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  {
    'updateImageProperties': {
      'objectId': object_id,
      'imageProperties': {
        'link': {
          'slideIndex': 2
        }
      },
      'fields': 'link'
    }
  }
]
```

The issue I have is that the image created has a link but it points to *"Invalid slide"*. If I look at the link it has this as value: `#slide=3`

If I use the `pageObjectId`property it does works but I need to set the slide index. Any clue on what might be happening here?

Comment: If you present you slides and click on the image - will it redirect you to the correct slide in spite of "Invalid slide"?

Comment: That's exactly correct. It does work :facepalm
Don't know how I didn't check that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### The issue you encountered is a bug

I filed it on your behalf on [Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/155348120) to make Google aware of the issue.